# Sharepoint and sending message with net send or msg.exe

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I need to send messages to users when items are added to a list. My requirement is not to use email or IM application. Could I use MSG or Net send as a solution and if so can somebody give me some pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure how to use net send from within a web application, or what the security restrictions/implications of doing that would be, but it may be possible

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/262560-net-send-using-c

Probably the best approach to this would be to code a custom event handler that attaches to your list and handles the ItemAdded event. You can specify whatever action you wish to take from within the event handler.